# WHERE CLAUSE & ORDER BY IN MYSQL PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause

Having scoured these boards I can't seem to find a response which gives me the solution to the error I'm seeing with the below statement - I believe I have the order of this correct but am likely missing something simple, I want to display only rows with an entry in 'postcode' and order the columns by the 'sort_order' parameter - see code below...

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT * FROM temptable
 where postcode<>''
 ORDER BY ' .  $column . ' ' . $sort_order)) {
```

Comment: change it to **if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM temptable
 where postcode<>''
 ORDER BY " .  $column . '" " . $sort_order)) {** you cant use ' as start/end of string and as empty string in one string or you must escape

Comment: It depends -- Is that inside single-quotes?  Double quotes?  A "here-doc"?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to escape the inner single quotes or use double quotes for the query string.

```php
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT * FROM temptable
     where postcode<>\'\'
     ORDER BY ' .  $column . ' ' . $sort_order)) {
```

or

```php
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM temptable
     where postcode <> ''
     ORDER BY $column $sort_order")) {
```

Make sure you are validating the values being passed in for `$column` and `$sort_order`, otherwise this will be a very simple SQL injection attack vulnerability. Better still, look into using prepared statements when building SQL queries which concatenate strings based on user input.

[Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)